# Issues with file naming when extracting JAR in JAVA

Tags: java, jar, filesystems, zip, compression

I have a jar generated by gradle (shadow jar to be more specific) on my mac.

When I list the jar contents:

```
... 
license 
LICENSE/licence.txt 
...
```

I'm using the ZipInputStream to go over the contents of the jar and to extract it to some folder (I iterate over the entries of the stream).

**When I encounter the LICENSE/licence.txt entry, I get an error as Java tries to create a dir with lowercase letters instead of the capital letters and there is already a file with lowercase letters so the operation fails (as the dir already exists).**

I believe that it's somehow related to the file system specifications but I would expect a correct behavior as the Jar was generated on the machine I also try to extract it to.

This is my unzip function -

```
public void unZipIt(String zipFile, String outputFolder){

 byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

 try{

    //create output directory is not exists
    File folder = new File(OUTPUT_FOLDER);
    if(!folder.exists()){
        folder.mkdir();
    }

    //get the zip file content
    ZipInputStream zis = 
        new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFile));
    //get the zipped file list entry
    ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();

    while(ze!=null){

       String fileName = ze.getName();
       File newFile = new File(outputFolder + File.separator + fileName);

       System.out.println("file unzip : "+ newFile.getAbsoluteFile());

        //create all non exists folders
        //else you will hit FileNotFoundException for compressed folder
        new File(newFile.getParent()).mkdirs();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);             

        int len;
        while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
           fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

        fos.close();   
        ze = zis.getNextEntry();
    }

    zis.closeEntry();
    zis.close();

    System.out.println("Done");

}catch(IOException ex){
   ex.printStackTrace(); 
}}
```

I get the following Exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/folders/4f/9d6qh2cs3rgdmt26ntvs551h006dg0/T/BABU7239734928498030055/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (Not a directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at com.waze.bi.emr.jobs.jobcopier.Util.unZipIt(Util.java:170)
    at com.waze.bi.emr.jobs.jobcopier.Util.main(Util.java:196)
```

Comment: Hi, please post your code so that I can check what might be wrong.

Comment: just added my unzip function

Comment: I don't seem to be abe to reproduce that on my linux. I can create 2 directories `license` and `LICENSE` at the same level. using File.mkdirs(). Can you post the trace of the error?

Comment: thanks for checking - added the exception i'm getting

Answer (score 0):

try to add `maven-toolchain` dependency to your pom.xml. it worked for me.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-toolchain</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.9</version>
</dependency>
```